# AzureDevops Release - Command Shell "do not have permissions"

Tags: shell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I've created a release on Azuredevops with a Command Line Task.
The script is really simple :
Unzip the artifcats and move it to another folder.

But owner's folder is not the same between the Agent Deployment and the repository.
I add chmod 777, it's works, but is not the best answer.

Do you have another solution ?

Comment: Use the Archive File task, which can zip and unzip in a variety of formats. No need to write your own script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> AzureDevops Release - Command Shell “do not have permissions”

Indeed, to unzip the artifcats and move it to another folder, we could use Extract Files task to complete this:

**[Extract Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/extract-files?view=azure-devops)**

> Use this task in a build or release pipeline to extract files from
>   archives to a target folder using match patterns. A range of standard
>   archive formats is supported, including .zip, .jar, .war, .ear, .tar,
>   .7z, and more.

BTW, there is an extension to Unzip a directories [Zip and unzip directory build task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=petergroenewegen.PeterGroenewegen-Xpirit-Vsts-Build-Zip&targetId=c519b80d-5d71-46b3-a8e0-3edf8c026ea2)

Hope this helps.